# how can I pass the 'customer address' to my new Mailer instance?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, swiftmailer, mailgun

I am making a dynamic sender, I put this code in a Service class**(AppServiceProvider.php)** or in a function that returns the Mailer object ready to be used.

```
 public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('user.id', function ($app, $parameters) {
        $smtp_host = array_get($parameters, 'smtp_host');
        $smtp_port = array_get($parameters, 'smtp_port');
        $smtp_username = array_get($parameters, 'smtp_username');
        $smtp_password = array_get($parameters, 'smtp_password');
        $smtp_encryption = array_get($parameters, 'smtp_encryption');
      
        $from_email = array_get($parameters, 'from_email');
        $from_name = array_get($parameters, 'from_name');
      
        $from_email = $parameters['from_email'];
        $from_name = $parameters['from_name'];
      
        $transport = new \Swift_SmtpTransport($smtp_host, $smtp_port);
        $transport->setUsername($smtp_username);
        $transport->setPassword($smtp_password);
        $transport->setEncryption($smtp_encryption);
      
        $swift_mailer = new \Swift_Mailer($transport);
      
        //$mailer = new Mail;
        $mailer = new Mailer($app->get('view'), $swift_mailer, $app->get('events'));
        $mailer->alwaysFrom($from_email, $from_name);
        $mailer->alwaysReplyTo($from_email, $from_name);
      
        return $mailer;
    });
}
```

this is my controller where I pass the arguments to the new instance 'mailer'.

```
public function email(DocumentEmailRequest $request)
{
    $user = Company::active();
    $company = Company::active();
    $document = Document::find($request->input('id'));
    $customer_email = $request->input('customer_email');

    $configuration = [
        'smtp_host'    => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'smtp_port'    => '465',
        'smtp_username'  => 'email@gmail.com',
        'smtp_password'  => 'password',
        'smtp_encryption'  => 'ssl',
       
        'from_email'    => 'email@gmail.com',
        'from_name'    => 'name',
       ];
       
    $mailer = app()->makeWith('user.id', $configuration);
    
    $mailer->to($customer_email)->send(new DocumentEmail($company, $document));

        return [
        'success' => true
    ];
}
```

I get this error:

> ```
> "Swift_RfcComplianceException" exception. line: 355 message: "The given mailbox address [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Sending email doesn't have to be complicated. Laravel provides a clean, simple email API powered by the popular SwiftMailer library. Laravel and [SwiftMailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/) provide drivers for sending email via SMTP, Mailgun, Postmark, Amazon SES, and sendmail, allowing you to quickly get started sending mail through a local or cloud based service of your choice.

Laravel's email services may be configured via your application's `config/mail.php` configuration file. **So I would recommend that you move this code to the correct section within the configuration**. Each mailer configured within this file may have its own unique configuration and even its own unique "transport", allowing your application to use different email services to send certain email messages. For example, your application might use Postmark to send transactional emails while using Amazon SES to send bulk emails.

Within your `mail` configuration file, you will find a `mailers` configuration array. This array contains a sample configuration entry for each of the major mail drivers / transports supported by Laravel, while the default configuration value determines which mailer will be used by `default` when your application needs to send an email message.

I strongly recommend you to follow the [official Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail). This way you will save yourself a lot of problems like this, and your code will be much cleaner than it is now.

Regarding the error that Laravel is returning, probably the `$customer_email` variable is empty or is not a valid email.

Comment: thanks for your answer, at the moment I am using 'config/mail.php' as it is in the official documentation, but I have a requirement that, all the mail sending, is dynamic, that each user uploads his configuration of host, ports, and so on. I have using multytenant, what do you recommend me, based on this context?

Comment: Are you offering a smtp service or something like that? Why do you allow each user to upload their own settings?